# STL exception messages on a unicode build

Tags: c++, c++11, unicode, stl, visual-studio-2013

`std::runtime_error::what()` returns `const char *` which is great in pre-unicode projects but is causing me some headaches trying to upgrade a project to build as unicode where `wchar_t` is the standard char type - we use TCHAR a lot which worked before and doesn't now!

Do wide-char STL exceptions exist or do I have to do a conversion myself?

Comment: You'll need to convert it yourself (or use one of the standard/platform conversion functions). The signature for `what()` is defined in the C++ to return a narrow `char`. Depending on where it is used, consider just overloading those functions for the `const char*` of the exception. It's what I've generally landed up doing.

Comment: You could encode you unicode error messages using e.g. UTF-8.

Comment: Go on then, someone give a sample code and get the answer points... I need to pass `e.what()` to `log(const TCHAR *msg)`

Comment: `TCHAR` is a major pain and really should not have been used past Windows ME. Then again, there's plenty of old C++ code around so this is still a reasonable question. Not to mention that new code still has to solve a similar problem with `log(std::wstring)`.

Comment: Should exception messages really contain localized text?